# Trying to calculate using a variable that has an unknown value (undefined)

Tags: python, arrays, variables, undefined

> for instance

```
   A=[array([[45225.35307609, 31425.35307609,     0.        ],
            [31425.35307609, 45225.35307609,     0.        ],
            [    0.        ,     0.        , 35609.38317306]]),
     array([[[ 22612.67653804,  15712.67653804, -16220.37580976],
             [ 15712.67653804,  22612.67653804, -16220.37580976],
             [-16220.37580976, -16220.37580976,  17804.69158653]]])] 

    exmax=unknown value variable #undefined maybe a better description?
    eymax=unknown value variable 
    exymax=unknown value variable 
    emax=np.array([[exmax],[eymax],[exymax]])

    N = np.dot(A,emax) #(where emax is a 3,1 array set up with three unknown variables)

#N must also equal 
N=np.array([[Nx],[0],[0]]) #where Nx is also undefined
```

> I want to set the N value equal to another value that contains a
> similarly undefined variable np.array([[Nx],[0],[0]]) and then
> calculate the values for emax.
> Each element of the A list should be multiplied by emax as well to
> give a list of these N values.
> I do not know the value of emax because I do not know the value of the
> three variables that make it up. I need to be able to set the unknown
> value of the emax matrix multiplied by the A matrix equal to N. While
> N also equals np.array(([Nx],[0],[0]]). Ultimately I need to be able
> to calculate for exmax, eymax, exymax, to get my emax matrix, while
> simultaneously being able to calculate NX in N.
> In this very specific case,

```
#N would be
np.array([[Nx],[0],[0]])=np.array([[45225exmax+31425eymax], [31425exmax + 45225eymax], [35609exymax]]) #for the first element in the A list.
```

This would mean that I can calculate for the emax's and the Nx.

Comment: Try to post an actual example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: And please form your code as code (`{}` button).

Comment: Better? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: What does `np.(A,emax)` mean? I don't think that's valid Python syntax.

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown value variable?" Are you trying to solve some system of equations? Can you give more information about the problem?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I meant to put np.dot(A,emax) my bad

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Also, I do not know the value of emax because I do not know the value of the three variables that make it up. I need to be able to set the unknown value of the emax matrix multiplied by the A matrix equal to N. While N also equals np.array(([Nx],[0],[0]]). Does that clarify things? Ultimately I need to be able to calculate for exmax, eymax, exymax, to get my emax matrix, while simultaneously being able to calculate NX in N.

Comment: In this very specific case, N would be np.array([[Nx],[0],[0]])=np.array([[45225exmax+31425eymax], [31425exmax + 45225eymax], [35609exymax]]) for the first element in the A list. This would mean that I can calculate for the ex's and the Nx.

Comment: My limited maths knowledge says you cannot solve for `4` unknown variables (`exmax`, `eymax`, `exymax`, `Nx`) from just the `3` equations that you have.

Comment: You can, only because Nx is in a matrix with two other values which are defined. Only reason this math works. You set each element in the  3,1 emax matrix that is generated to each element in the 3,1 N matrix equal to each other (as if they were zipped) and then you can solve all for all variables.